# How to change Azure DevOps environment agent folder structure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-services

To achieve continuous deployment, we used a (classic) release pipeline on Azure DevOps to deploy a webservice to a VM in our intranet. To benefit of a yaml deployment pipeline, I replaced our former deployment pool agent on that VM with an environment agent.

For the actual deployment, we use the [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops). The source directory for this tasks defaults to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip`. The `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` translates to the `a` subdirectory of the concrete release.

Unfortunately for me, the environment agent downloads the artifact *next* to the `a`-folder instead of *into* it like the environment pool agent. Thus the default settings of the deploy task cannot find it. I am aware that I can easily work around this issue by using `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\..\**\*.zip`. I was just wondering why Microsoft introduced such a development speed bump into the environment agents.

**Is there any way I can make the environment agent download the artifact into `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` aka. `a` instead of next to it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using deployment job in yaml pipeline. The artifacts will be automatically downloaded to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/`(folder next to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`) in deployment jobs. See below extract from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download):

- Artifacts from the current pipeline are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.
- Artifacts from the associated pipeline resource are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace)/{pipeline resource identifier}/.
- All available artifacts from the current pipeline and from the associated pipeline resources are automatically downloaded in deployment jobs and made available for your deployment. To prevent downloads, specify download: none.

**To make the environment agent download the artifact into $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).**

You can specify `download: none`. And use [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) and specify the `path`  parameter to download your artifacts to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. See below:

```
 - deployment: 
   environment: Dev
   strategy:
     runOnce:    
       deploy:
         steps:
         - download: none #prevent automatically download

         - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
           inputs:
             buildType: 'current'
             targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'  # download to default folder.
```

Anther workaround is to change the source directory for `IIS Web App Deploy task` defaults to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\**\*.zip`

Answer (score 1):

When changing from Classic to YAML pipelines for deployments, you will probably need to change `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`. You can verify this with the steps:

```yaml
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Recurse
  displayName: Check System.DefaultWorkingDirectory
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem $(Pipeline.Workspace) -Recurse
  displayName: Check Pipeline.Workspace
```

(Yes, this is an awfully verbose way of doing it. It will, though, give you more complete insight into the file structure supporting your job.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to configure the azure env. then cd the drive and change the script "SystemDrive" with your drive name.

```
cd $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'
```